# How can I search for MP3 files by the "Purchased By" field?

Tags: itunes, search, mp3

As I sort through thousands of MP3 files in iTunes, I notice that I have many files that are DRM and "Purchased By" another Apple ID (that I have no access to).  How would you locate those MP3 files, searching for the name in the Purchased By field?

Answer (score 1):

In Itunes, create a Smart Playlist and name it purchases.  (File Menu, New Playlist... Smart Playlist)

In the search parameters of the smart playlist, Choose 'Purchased' and 'IS True'. That's the closes you'll get to sorting out your purchased items, but it doesn't allow you to sort by apple ID.

[image: smart playlist]

Since iTunes doesn't allow you to search the 'Purchased by' field in filters, you can accomplish this using Tracksift, by dougscripts.com.

I tried, and using applescript doesn't easily lend itself to reveal the 'purchased by' property, from what I can find.

http://dougscripts.com/apps/tracksift2app.php

This app allows you to Sort tracks into playlists by Apple ID.

Comment: Bille, Tracksift 2 is perfect. Made a playlist for each Apple ID. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The current way to do this is with [Track Down Purchases](https://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=mxtrackdownpurchases) from Doug (of iTunes AppleScript fame). This is a script that will create playlists for you for each purchaser so you can process them as you like (using other smart playlists).[image: screenshot]